# DataGridView TextBox Column - Show Right Part of Text when Text is Long

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, ellipsis

I have a `DataGridView` in windows forms which has a column that I don't want to set it to be auto-size to fit all text.

Instead I want to display the right part of the text when the text is long. Is this possible?

For example:

- Text for a cell is: `Some long text`
- Currently width is such that only this displays: `Some long`
- I would like it to show the right most part of text at first: `long text`

Then to see the whole text, the user can resize the column width. It's opposite of default behavior. In default behavior, it shows the left part of text with ellipsis at the end of string, and to see the right part user have to change column width.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I right-align text in a DataGridView column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230316/how-can-i-right-align-text-in-a-datagridview-column)

Comment: @Luke right-aligning the text is not the solution. When the text is long, for example `Some long text`, it will display `Some lo...` while the OP need the text be shown as `long text` or `...ng text`. The op need the right part of text be shown first. It's not about right-aligning. Take a look at screenshots in my answer.

Comment: @RezaAghaei As you probably can imagine i read the question myself, so there was no reason to quote it. I also haven't tested it, which is the reason there is a questionmark in that comment. Think about it this way; Default Text Align = Left so it displays the left part first (besides the rest assignment does). So why shouldnt you give right alignment a try to also show the right part first? Not saying it must work, just saying you should give it a try before handling the whole paintevent yourself.

Comment: @Luke It's just a comment for your information! You proposed something that you even didn't perform a simple test for it. I know you read the question but you didn't test the right-align. If you set text align to right, it just draws the string at right side. Also for long strings the behavior is what I described

Comment: @Luke I know you tried to help and it's the important part :) Let's focus on technical details.

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this question! The solution below is awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main idea is handling [`CellPainting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView` and measure length of string using `TextRenderer.MeasureText` and check if the string is longer than width of cell, draw string at right of cell otherwise, draw it at left side.

**Note:** Please note, right-aligning the text is not the solution. If you use right-aligning, When the text is long, for example `Some long text`, it will display `Some lo...` while the OP need the text be shown as `long text` or `...ng text`. The op need the right part of text be shown first. It's not about right-aligning.

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        var rect = e.CellBounds;
        rect.Inflate(-1, 0);
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All
            & ~(DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground));
        var text = string.Format("{0}", e.FormattedValue);
        var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, e.CellStyle.Font);
        var flags = TextFormatFlags.Left;
        if (size.Width > rect.Width)
            flags = TextFormatFlags.Right;
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, e.CellStyle.Font,
            rect, e.CellStyle.ForeColor, flags | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**Left image:** For long strings, you see the right part of string in cell. Short string appearance is normal.

**Right Image:** The column got wider so appearance is normal.

[image]
[image]

**Showing Ellipsis at beginning of string**

But the appearance is somehow confusing for users and they don't know which cell has more text and which one doesn't have more text. In such cases, showing ellipsis is really useful and based on your preferences, ellipsis should be shown at beginning of the string this way:

[image]

But the problem is drawing a string with ellipsis at the beginning of the string.

There is a useful [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37503/Auto-Ellipsis) written by Thomas Polaert. I made some small changes to the class which he shared to calculate a string with start ellipsis based on the string, available width, the font and graphics object which will draw the string. I've posted changed code  at the end of this post.

The only change which you need to make is calculating the text with ellipsis:

```
var text = string.Format("{0}", e.FormattedValue);
text = AutoEllipsis.Ellipsis.Compact(text, e.Graphics, e.CellBounds.Width,
    e.CellStyle.Font, AutoEllipsis.EllipsisFormat.Start);
```

The rest of code is untouched and the result would be a string with ellipsis at the beginning despite the default behavior which shows ellipsis at the end.

**AutoEllipsis**

The original code relies on a `Control`. I changed it a bit to pass `Graphics` object, `Font` and `Width` which we want to use to calculate auto ellipis:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace AutoEllipsis
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies ellipsis format and alignment.
    /// </summary>
    [Flags]
    public enum EllipsisFormat
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Text is not modified.
        /// </summary>
        None = 0,
        /// <summary>
        /// Text is trimmed at the end of the string. An ellipsis (...) is drawn in place of remaining text.
        /// </summary>
        End = 1,
        /// <summary>
        /// Text is trimmed at the begining of the string. An ellipsis (...) is drawn in place of remaining text. 
        /// </summary>
        Start = 2,
        /// <summary>
        /// Text is trimmed in the middle of the string. An ellipsis (...) is drawn in place of remaining text.
        /// </summary>
        Middle = 3,
        /// <summary>
        /// Preserve as much as possible of the drive and filename information. Must be combined with alignment information.
        /// </summary>
        Path = 4,
        /// <summary>
        /// Text is trimmed at a word boundary. Must be combined with alignment information.
        /// </summary>
        Word = 8
    }


    public class Ellipsis
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// String used as a place holder for trimmed text.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly string EllipsisChars = "...";

        private static Regex prevWord = new Regex(@"\W*\w*$");
        private static Regex nextWord = new Regex(@"\w*\W*");

        /// <summary>
        /// Truncates a text string to fit within a given control width by replacing trimmed text with ellipses. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">String to be trimmed.</param>
        /// <param name="ctrl">text must fit within ctrl width.
        /// The ctrl's Font is used to measure the text string.</param>
        /// <param name="options">Format and alignment of ellipsis.</param>
        /// <returns>This function returns text trimmed to the specified witdh.</returns>
        public static string Compact(string text, Graphics g, int width, Font font, EllipsisFormat options)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                return text;

            // no aligment information
            if ((EllipsisFormat.Middle & options) == 0)
                return text;

            if (g == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("g");

            Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, text, font);

            // control is large enough to display the whole text
            if (s.Width <= width)
                return text;

            string pre = "";
            string mid = text;
            string post = "";

            bool isPath = (EllipsisFormat.Path & options) != 0;

            // split path string into <drive><directory><filename>
            if (isPath)
            {
                pre = Path.GetPathRoot(text);
                mid = Path.GetDirectoryName(text).Substring(pre.Length);
                post = Path.GetFileName(text);
            }

            int len = 0;
            int seg = mid.Length;
            string fit = "";

            // find the longest string that fits into 
            // the control boundaries using bisection method
            while (seg > 1)
            {
                seg -= seg / 2;

                int left = len + seg;
                int right = mid.Length;

                if (left > right)
                    continue;

                if ((EllipsisFormat.Middle & options) == EllipsisFormat.Middle)
                {
                    right -= left / 2;
                    left -= left / 2;
                }
                else if ((EllipsisFormat.Start & options) != 0)
                {
                    right -= left;
                    left = 0;
                }

                // trim at a word boundary using regular expressions
                if ((EllipsisFormat.Word & options) != 0)
                {
                    if ((EllipsisFormat.End & options) != 0)
                    {
                        left -= prevWord.Match(mid, 0, left).Length;
                    }
                    if ((EllipsisFormat.Start & options) != 0)
                    {
                        right += nextWord.Match(mid, right).Length;
                    }
                }

                // build and measure a candidate string with ellipsis
                string tst = mid.Substring(0, left) + EllipsisChars + mid.Substring(right);

                // restore path with <drive> and <filename>
                if (isPath)
                {
                    tst = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(pre, tst), post);
                }
                s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, tst, font);

                // candidate string fits into control boundaries, try a longer string
                // stop when seg <= 1
                if (s.Width <= width)
                {
                    len += seg;
                    fit = tst;
                }
            }

            if (len == 0) // string can't fit into control
            {
                // "path" mode is off, just return ellipsis characters
                if (!isPath)
                    return EllipsisChars;

                // <drive> and <directory> are empty, return <filename>
                if (pre.Length == 0 && mid.Length == 0)
                    return post;

                // measure "C:\...\filename.ext"
                fit = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(pre, EllipsisChars), post);

                s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, fit, font);

                // if still not fit then return "...\filename.ext"
                if (s.Width > width)
                    fit = Path.Combine(EllipsisChars, post);
            }
            return fit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello somehow my original question got moved to here and cannot read this.  this was not what I was asking.. I did not ask for ellipsis at the beginning of the text field.  I asked to scoll to show the right part of the text value, and then be able to scroll to the left and see the full data.  this solution not does show the full text and be able to view it.

Comment: @dan Hello :) No problem, I changed your question back to it's original requirements. I thought you don't know `ellipsis` but you mean `ellipsis` so I added some description about it. Now the question is just like it's original version but more clear. I also edited the answer to support both with/without ellipsis. Hope you find it useful :)

Comment: thank you.  not sure what you mean by ellipsis but anyway I see my original question, thanks.

Comment: By the way, did you read the answer? Isn't the first screenshot what you are looking for?

Comment: HI - yes actually that is what I was looking for - the CellPainting event - I missed it... but cells that fit within the column width does have a space on the left side, but I was able to tweak it by not including VerticalCenter in the flags... thanks for your help!

Comment: btw I am not able to mark your original reply as answer to question... is it marked?  if not can you do that?  thanks ...

Comment: Btw, You can accept an answer by click on check mark near the answer. Also when you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the post. It's not compulsory at all, but it's common, reasonable and recommended. For more information about how does accepting answers work see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: upvote for this works nicely, I have tweaked it to not have to provide the graphics, `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` works with just the width and the font.